# why XML file tags is not display in firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

i have xslt file look like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

  <xsl:output
       method="xml"
       encoding="utf-8"
       media-type="application/xml"
       cdata-section-elements="shortdescription"
  />
  <xsl:template match='/'>

    <items>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="response/result/doc"/>
    </items>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- search results xslt -->
  <xsl:template match="doc">

      <Id><xsl:value-of select="$Id"/></Id>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and its display Id in firefox 31 look like:

```
52256
```

expected output like:

```
<Id>52256</Id>
```

**Note**:- In Google Chrome browser its working fine

pls help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are running XSLT in the browser then most browsers assume you want to render the transformation result, Firefox does that with XSLT transformation results and if you render an element that contains a text node the text node's content is displayed. Firefox does not serialize the result tree of an XSLT transformation at all, unless you use Javascript to run the transformation and use `XMLSerializer` in Javascript explicitly to serialize a DOM tree.

Also note that your whole sample is looking rather odd, it uses `version="2.0"` although browsers only support XSLT 1.0, it references a variable that is not declared.

Comment: hello Martin i have update xslt 1.0 to 2.0 but its occurred same issue on firefox 31

Comment: And how to use XMLSerializer in xslt?

Comment: Firefox does not support XSLT 2.0 at all, nor does any other browser. And if you use XSLT in Firefox to transform XML to XML then Firefox renders the result tree which makes sense for XHTML or SVG or MathML, it might not make sense for your target format but then don't do XSLT in the browser or do it with Javascript.

Comment: Hello Martin i have also checked on xslt 1.0 its occurred same issue

Comment: @JatinPatel, both my answer and my comment are trying to tell you that Firefox does not support what you want and that doing XML to XML transformation in the browser is meant to transform an input XML format to an output XML format the browser knows to render, like XHTML and/or SVG and/or MathML in the case of Firefox. If you want to transform to an arbitrary XML format and need the serialized result then don't try Firefox, use a standalone XSLT processor or an XML editor.